# numbers: Copy/paste of cells messes up my formular

Tags: numbers

When I copy a cell (see picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmwSH.png)) and paste it (see picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqQD3.png)) the pasted version of the formular is messed up.

As you can see there are some parts of the pasted formular which are not colored anymore. It seems as the text there got truncated.

Any idea what the cause of this is?

Peace!

[image: This looks okay (copy)]

[image: This is wiered (pasted)]

Comment: I think it depends on how it recognizes your data table.

Comment: What do you mean? What can I do that it recognizes it better? I mean, how could it be that "Planned Expenses :: Amount" gets "Planned Expenses :: E"? Where the heck is the "E" coming from from?

Comment: Do you have headers for both rows and columns?

Comment: Do you mean, if I have selected in the Inspector that the table have "Header & Footer"? If so, yes. 1 Header row and one 1 header column...

Comment: Then this seems weird, because as far as I know, it will automatically use those headers and footers in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

when this has happened to me it has been a big pain, and happens more often than I would think, even copy/pasting from Apple's own templates after I've filled them out.

Sometimes it is because of the 'relativity' of the function.

- Hover over the color-highlighted cell id (i.e. C7, or B7 in my example) and a little 'circle-down-arrow' will appear (in either the function area under the toolbar, or by bringing up a function pop-up by double clicking a cell).
- click on it and you will see the 'relativity menu' in my image below that begins with:
   "*(checkmark) (B7) relative*"
- You can get more info in help by reading in the built-in help menu:
  "*Distinguishing Absolute and Relative Cell References*"

Sometimes however, the cause has to do with *what* the 'Cell Format' is in the relative cells in question that the pasted formula would reference

- see the lower left portion of my image below (arrived at by clicking the inspector, then the [42] tab).

[image: numbers relative function menu and cell format inspector pane]

I can sometimes, but not always seem to solve my pasted formula woes by one or both of the above.

- Also, just to be sure, the intended *newly* referenced cells do indeed *exist*, otherwise my solutions will not be applicable, as there are no such cells to which you can refer in your formulae!